# Likert scale dependent variables

Tags: likert, scales

I am doing a research about the ethics in pharmaceutical industry. I've chosen 7 branding activities followed by pharmaceutical companies.

I want to study the relationship between the perception of ethics in those activities by doctors and how that might affect their prescription behavior. My hypothesis is that more ethical perception can result into better doctors' response.

I used a likert scale of 5 points to identify both "the perception" and "the response" for each activity.

How can I analyze? What tool can better answer my question? should I analysis each activity separately or is there a tool to consider all of them as a whole?

Comment: I think this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158899/correlation-between-different-likert-scales should be answering your question. If not, you 'd have to provide more information on the type of variables and study hypotheses